# Subtract quantities from an excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x

the first part of my code compares an Excel file with the columns "good" and "quantity" with three Excel files, the file that contains the best percentage of "quantity" compared to the first file is printed to me. In the second part, however, I would like the quantity of the first file to be subtracted from the corresponding quantity of the file with the best percentage.

```py
def confronta_somma_e_percentuali(file1_path, file2_path, file3_path, file4_path):
    global miglior_file
    global percentuali
    
    # Carica i dati dai quattro file Excel
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1_path)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2_path)
    df3 = pd.read_excel(file3_path)
    df4 = pd.read_excel(file4_path)

    # Calcola la somma delle quantità per ogni bene dal primo file
    somma_df1 = df1.groupby('Bene')['Quantità'].sum().reset_index()

    # Unisci i dati basandoti sulla colonna "Beni" per ogni file
    df_merge2 = pd.merge(somma_df1, df2, on='Bene', how='inner', suffixes=('_file1', 'centro 1'))
    df_merge3 = pd.merge(somma_df1, df3, on='Bene', how='inner', suffixes=('_file1', 'centro 2'))
    df_merge4 = pd.merge(somma_df1, df4, on='Bene', how='inner', suffixes=('_file1', 'centro 3'))

    # Calcola le percentuali e identifica il file con la miglior percentuale
    percentuali = {}

    for df_merge, file_suffix in zip([df_merge2, df_merge3, df_merge4], ['centro 1', 'centro 2', 'centro 3']):
        quantità_file1 = df_merge['Quantità_file1']
        quantità_file2 = df_merge['Quantità' + file_suffix]

        # Calcola la percentuale
        percentuale = quantità_file2 / quantità_file1 * 100

        # Memorizza la percentuale nel dizionario
        percentuali[file_suffix] = percentuale

    miglior_file = max(percentuali, key=lambda k: percentuali[k].max())

    print(f"La miglior percentuale è ottenuta dal {miglior_file}:\n{percentuali[miglior_file]}")

    # Aggiorna la colonna "Quantità" del file con la miglior percentuale
    miglior_file_df = df2 if miglior_file == 'centro 1' else (df3 if miglior_file == 'centro 2' else df4)
    miglior_file_df['Quantità'] = miglior_file_df['Quantità'] - somma_df1['Quantità']

    # Salva il DataFrame aggiornato nel file Excel originale
    miglior_file_df.to_excel(file2_path if miglior_file == 'centro 1' else (file3_path if miglior_file == 'centro 2' else file4_path), index=False)

    # Crea un nuovo DataFrame con il contenuto di file1_path
    nuovo_df = pd.read_excel(file1_path)

    # Cancella tutto il contenuto di file1_path
    pd.DataFrame().to_excel(file1_path, index=False)

    # Salva il DataFrame nel nuovo file Excel "nuovo_file1.xlsx"
    nuovo_df.to_excel("nuovo_file1.xlsx", index=False)
```